# Qt NumberAnimation property binding loop problem

Tags: qt, qml

I am new to Qt QML. I am dynamically creating a numberAnimation using JS but getting binding loop warning.

**qrc:/main.qml:18:9: QML Item: Binding loop detected for property "anime"**

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12

Window {
    id : global
    width: 550
    height: 550
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Rectangle{
        id : exp
        x : 0
        y : 0
        color : "red"
        width : 50 ; height : 50

        property var anime : createAnimation(exp);

        function createAnimation(parent){
            let numAnime = Qt.createQmlObject("import QtQuick 2.12; NumberAnimation { onStopped:{to = Math.random()*500; restart() }}", parent)
            numAnime.duration = 500
            numAnime.easing.type = Easing.OutInSine
            numAnime.target = parent
            numAnime.property = "x"
            numAnime.running = true
            return numAnime
        }
    }
}
```

Also, is there a way to define onStopped body within the createAnimation(args) function?

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the binding on `anime` by assigning it in `Component.onCompleted`. And yes, you can define `onStopped` in the body of `createAnimation` by connecting it to a function, like this:

```
    Rectangle{
        id : exp
        x : 0
        y : 0
        color : "red"
        width : 50 ; height : 50

        property var anime
        Component.onCompleted: anime = createAnimation(exp);

        function createAnimation(parent){
            let numAnime = Qt.createQmlObject("import QtQuick 2.12; NumberAnimation {}", parent)
            numAnime.duration = 500
            numAnime.easing.type = Easing.OutInSine
            numAnime.target = parent
            numAnime.property = "x"
            numAnime.running = true
            numAnime.onStopped.connect(function() { numAnime.to = Math.random() * 500; numAnime.restart() })
            return numAnime
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is what exactly I was looking for. But can you explain why there was binding loop in the first place ?

Comment: I'm actually not sure the reason, no.